# DateDiff DateInterval.WeekOfYear returning inconsistent results

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder

I'm having an issue with a calculation to remove weekend days between two dates. The full formula is...

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.day, Fields!FromTime.Value, Fields!ToTime.Value) + 1)
 - (DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!FromTime.Value, Fields!ToTime.Value) * 2)
 - (iif(Weekday(Fields!FromTime.Value) = 7, 1, 0)
 - (iif(Weekday(Fields!ToTime.Value) = 6, 1, 0))
 - 1)
```

...but I've isolated my specific issue to the DateDiff part (`DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!FromTime.Value, Fields!ToTime.Value)`) as this is not always counting the difference correctly.

Attached table (filtered on DateDiff=1) shows the year week "from" and "to" parts and then the final column is returning the DateDiff calculation. Comparing the To/From weeks you can see some are more than one week difference although the calculation is always returning 1?

[Table of Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPxlC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, which returns qty of week days between two dates:

```
=(DateDiff("d",Fields!FromTime.Value,Fields!ToTime.Value)) - (
(((DateDiff
(DateInterval.Day,
DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,7-WeekDay(Fields!FromTime.Value),Fields!FromTime.Value),
DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,7- 
WeekDay(Fields!ToTime.Value),Fields!ToTime.Value).AddDays(1)) + 1)/ 7)*2)
+
iif(weekday(Fields!ToTime.Value)=7,1,0)
 +
iif(weekday(Fields!FromTime.Value)=1,1,0)
-1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of the issue myself, for some reason SSRS didn't like doing a DateDiff week comparison on a date & time string (possibly the magnitude was too great?). So my solution was to find the DateDiff against just the date part, covert that to seconds and then take away the result from the original DateDiff on seconds.

```
=DateDiff(Dateinterval.Second, Fields!FromTime.Value, Fields!ToTimeNow.Value, FirstDayOfWeek.Monday, FirstWeekOfYear.FirstFullWeek)
- ((DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!FromDate.Value, Fields!ToDate.Value, FirstDayOfWeek.Monday, FirstWeekOfYear.FirstFullWeek) * 2) * 86400)
- iif(Weekday(Fields!FromDate.Value, 1) = 1, 86400, 0)
- iif(Weekday(Fields!FromDate.Value, 1) = 7, 86400, 0)
- iif(Weekday(Fields!ToDate.Value, 1) = 1, 86400, 0)
- iif(Weekday(Fields!ToDate.Value, 1) = 7, 86400, 0)
```